# Inserting Data from local server into online server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

We have two server. I want to synchronize tables from different server. I want to insert some data from server 1 into a table from server2. How can I do that in mysql or PHP mysqli?

Comment: You need to provide more details. What did you try ? Show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a while loop, connect to the source server, 
query the data from the source server into an array, 
Explode the array into variables with for each loop
Close the connection
Connect to the second server and insert
Close the connection.